# Why does a task named 'foo-test' throw an error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rake-task

A task defined as `task :foo => :environment do` runs fine, but the same task defined as `task :foo-test => :environment do` throws the error 
`rake aborted!
wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)`.

Why?

Comment: `test` is generally a reserved word. I know this because I often forget and create `test_db`, `test_table` and `test_task` getting all sorts of errors.

Comment: So, are there "reserved" rake tasks that end in '-test'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:foo-test` is actually just `:foo - test`, you need to either name it `:foo_test` or `:'foo-test'`.

Comment: That's because `:foo-bar` is `:foo - bar`, you're trying to subtract the variable `bar` (most likely undefined) from the symbol `:foo`.